# How can I open all urls in my browser with xdg-open?

Tags: kde, plasma, xdg-open

`xdg-open` opens normal web pages in Firefox, such as `xdg-open http://google.com`. However, images do not. For example, `xdg-open https://i.imgur.com/JfKwovX.jpg` opens the image in Gwenview. I [tried](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open) setting Firefox as default for (all?) urls with

```
xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for `*.jpg` urls. How can I make `xdg-open` open *all* urls in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by going to `System Settings -> Applications -> Web Browser` and setting parameter `Open http and https URLs` to `in the following browser -> firefox`[image: System settings screenshot]

This works with KDE 5, but should work similar in previous versions.

Comment: This seems like it should work… but it doesn't! It was originally on the first option, but changing it to the second made no difference; it still opens in Gwenview. I even did `kbuildsycoca5; kquitapp5 plasmashell; plasmashell`.

Comment: @Sparhawk It's strange. Have you tried to upgrade to the lastest version, recheck settings and reboot (or restart all applications including plasma)?

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux with a fully updated system. I restarted just in case, but there was no difference… but after the restart it had reverted, and changing this setting again fixed it! Thanks.